# Swift "can not increment endIndex" when deleting Japanese characters

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'm using Swift 2.0/Xcode 7.0 for an iOS app. I've built a Japanese IME to convert Roman characters to their Japanese equivalent. For example:

- Typing "a" will convert the "a" to "あ"
- Typing a "k" will do nothing (no match in Japanese) until the next character is typed, for example typing a "k" then an "a" will result in "か"

My problem is when I try to delete a Japanese character. If there is only one character in the text field, the delete key/function works as expected. However, if there is more than one, when I try to delete the character, I receive a `can not increment endIndex` error in the following code.

```
var imeInputLength: Int = 0

let currentInputValue: String = txtfldYourResponse.text!.lowercaseString

if(currentInputValue.characters.count==0) {
    imeInputLength = 0
}

let inputStringToKeep: String = currentInputValue.substringWithRange(
    Range<String.Index>(start: currentInputValue.startIndex.advancedBy(imeInputLength), 
    end: currentInputValue.endIndex))

let imeStringToKeep: String = currentInputValue.substringWithRange(
    Range<String.Index>(start: currentInputValue.startIndex, 
    end: currentInputValue.startIndex.advancedBy(imeInputLength)))

    if let imeValueDC = JIMEDC[inputStringToKeep] {
        txtfldYourResponse.text = imeStringToKeep + imeValueDC
        imeInputLength = (txtfldYourResponse.text?.characters.count)!-1
    }

    if let imeValue = JIME[inputStringToKeep] {
        txtfldYourResponse.text = imeStringToKeep + imeValue
        imeInputLength = txtfldYourResponse.text!.characters.count
    }
```

`currentInputValue` is the text from the text field.

`imeInputLength` is an `int` (initial value = 0) that increments by the total character count in the text field AFTER a match is found.

`JIMEDC` and `JIME` are key/value pairs that handle the conversion from Roman to Japanese characters.

I'm printing the `endIndex` to the console before the code runs. It appears to increment/decrement as expected, but the code block above fails with the increment error.

I've been banging my head against this for a couple weeks now with no progress.

**Edit:** Clarified handling of `imeInputLength` and added additional code for clarification.

Comment: Why are you resetting the value `imeInputLength` back to zero each time?

Comment: `imeInputLength` keeps track of how many Roman characters have been typed to be able to look up the Japanese character from another object. The value increments by 1 each time a match is not found. When the matching Japanese character is found, `imeInputLength` is reset to 0 to start looking for the next set of Roman characters.

Comment: That's the problem though — each time you reset it you are making `advancedBy` = `0`, so `endIndex` can't increment.

Comment: Sorry... that's a mistake on my part. I don't set it back to 0 until I reset the text field for the next entry. It increments by 1 each time a match is found. I'll update the original question.

Comment: I see; I guess it's not real clear on why you need to do that whole process really. When the block fails is `imeInputLength` equal to `0` or is it some other value, and what is it in comparison to `endIndex` when it fails?

Comment: The process is used to keep the converted Japanese characters while trimming off the Roman characters that are used to look up the Japanese equivalent. It all works fine other than when I push the delete key.

If I type "umare", I'll have three converted characters (うまれ). The `endIndex` is 4 (expected) and the `imeInputLength` is 3 (count of the converted characters). When I hit delete, I'd expect `endIndex` to decrement by 1 (or increment by -1?). If the code was reachable, `imeInputLength` would be set to 2.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90965/discussion-between-robert-and-lll).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A side conversation with l'L'l got me on the right track. I was confused by the error message `can not increment endIndex`. In reality, I was creating an out-of-bounds error on my range.

When the backspace key was pressed, I wasn't modifying `imeInputLength` to reflect the new length of the input string. As a result, my `advanceBy`amount was larger than the updated `endIndex` value. Swift threw this as `can not increment endIndex` but the reason for it was the `startIndex` was now greater than the `endIndex`.

I resolved this by first checking for the following:

```
if(imeInputLength > currentInputValue.characters.count) {
    print("You must have pressed backspace")
    imeInputLength = txtfldYourResponse.text!.characters.count
} else {
    let inputStringToKeep:
    ...
}
```

If the backspace key IS pressed, I needed to see if the `imeInputLength` value was greater than the current character count of the input field. The only use case where `imeInputLength` ends up greater is when a Japanese character is deleted using the backspace key. When this condition is caught, I reset `imeInputLength` to the current character count and exit the routine.

I'm happy to say that all of my use cases now test out positive!